# PHP MYSQL: Return rows for each unique entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to set up a PHP script that records visitors on my website, with geolocation.
I am trying to edit the code to result how many hits I have for each country, like US: 14; GB: 2; and so on... 
This is the code that returns "132" on each column, so no unique hits for each country.

```
$squery = 'SELECT `gcountry`, `dtime` FROM `allowed`'; 
$ress = mysqli_query($conn, $squery);
echo '<style>.tables {margin-left: 6cm;}</style>';  
echo '<table border="1" class="tables">';
echo'<th><font color="white">Country</font></th><th><font color="white">Date / Time</font></th><font color="white">Hits</font></th>';

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($ress))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><font color="white">&nbsp;'.$data['gcountry'].'&nbsp;</font></td><td><font color="white">'.$data['dtime'].'&nbsp;</font></td><td><font color="white">'.mysqli_affected_rows($conn).'&nbsp;</font></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Edited the post, so...
Here is the code, and attaching table entries:

```
$squery = 'SELECT gcountry,COUNT(*) FROM allowed GROUP BY gcountry';
$ress = mysqli_query($conn, $squery);

echo '<style>.tables {margin-left: 6cm;}</style>';
echo '<table border="1" class="tables">'; echo'<th><font color="white">Country</font></th><font color="white">Hits</font></th>'; 

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($ress)) {
    echo'<tr>';
    echo '<td><font color="white">&nbsp;'.$data['gcountry'].'&nbsp;</font></td><td><td><font color="white">'.mysqli_affected_rows($conn).'&nbsp;</font></td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

---

Table content:

```
IP               |  UserAgent                 |       GCOUNTRY             |    GCITY                   | DTIME
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          GB                | London                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RU                | Moscow                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          GB                | London                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          GB                | London                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          US                | Lombard                    | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          US                | San Antonio                | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Constanta                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Bucharest                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Iasi                       | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          NL                | Amsterdam                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          US                | Fort Lauderdale            | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Constanta                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Constanta                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RO                | Bucharest                  | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          RU                | Moscow                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          US                | Irving                     | 21-08-2016
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  |Mozilla Firefox ....        |          US                | Anaheim                    | 21-08-2016
```

Comment: give some more details. Columns in database from where you are extracting this data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ray. Database name: Tracking; Table name: allowed; Columns: IP, UA, GCOUNTRY, GCITY, DTIME. I am trying to extract just all hits from each country in the gcountry column

Comment: @Chris is correct. Just use this and check `$squery = 'SELECT `gcountry`,COUNT(*) FROM allowed GROUP BY `gcountry`'; `

Comment: I did, and it resulted in getting ALL visits, returning "16" for each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the `COUNT` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html), and how it can be used with [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html):

> Earlier, you retrieved the names of the people who owned pets. You can use `COUNT()` if you want to find out how many pets each owner has:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT owner, COUNT(*) FROM pet GROUP BY owner;
>
> +--------+----------+
> | owner  | COUNT(*) |
> +--------+----------+
> | Benny  |        2 |
> | Diane  |        2 |
> | Gwen   |        3 |
> | Harold |        2 |
> +--------+----------+
> ```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your reply. If I'm trying to use 'SELECT gcountry, dtime COUNT(*) FROM `allowed` GROUP BY `gcountry`'; it gives me this error:  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in .........

Comment: What would you expect `dtime` to contain if you're only showing a single row per country? MySQL doesn't know how to reduce multiple values down to one since you haven't used a grouping function on that column. The SQL query fails, so [`mysqli_query` returns `false`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), and you can't get results from it with `mysqli_fetch_array`. Try taking `dtime` out of the query.

Comment: Same error for: 'SELECT `gcountry` COUNT(*) FROM `allowed` GROUP BY `gcountry`';

Comment: @unkn0wnx, please make sure to check `$ress` and make sure it's a `mysqli_result` object. If it's not, use [`mysqli_error`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what the MySQL error is.

Comment: Thanks Chris, however, this query `'SELECT COUNT(*), `gcountry` FROM allowed GROUP BY `gcountry`'` will return 16 to all rows.

Comment: @unkn0wnx, is it possible that there are actually 16 visits for each country? I believe my answer is correct, and I just tested it successfully on my own machine.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time Chris, but I just manually removed some entries from the table, and for example for GB countries there are only 3 visits now, and it still returns 16.

Comment: @unkn0wnx, could you please use the edit link on your question and add the exact query (copy and paste) that you're using? And if it's not too big, please also add the table and its contents.

Comment: Done! I have edited the post and added table content.

Comment: @unkn0wnx, you are outputting `mysqli_affected_rows()` in your HTML. This is the _number of rows in the result set_. Instead, try outputting `$data['count(*)']`, which is the count column in your query.

Comment: @unkn0wnx, it looks like you used caps in your query. Try `COUNT(*)` as your index. This is literally just pulling a column out of your result based on the columns on your SQL query. It is probably worth inspecting `$data` with `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc. Inspecting values is an important skill when programming.

Comment: Thank you so so much, for all your time. '.$data['COUNT(*)'] works, it gives me the correct values. Thank you very much!